# iOS: will my iPad-only app be rejected from AppStore if it's built using armv6?

Tags: ios, ipad, architecture, arm

iPads run armv7, and if the app is only for iPad, it should be compiled for armv7 (optimized) architecture.

However I have to use a library that's only available as armv6, forcing my app to be armv6. Will that cause my app to be rejected from the AppStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but assuming the app will run as such, being  built only for arm6, I don't think it will be rejected. I didn't see anything about architecture on the [App Store review Guidelines page](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).